# SQL query for formatted output

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a SQL query, and also format the output of that query.

My table looks like this:

```
Time    Amount  Id  iMId
---------------------------------
  1      2500   1   4
  3      5000   1   4
  5     10000   1   4
  7     20000   1   4
  1      2500   2   8
  3      5000   2   8
  5     10000   2   8
  7     20000   2   8
```

I want the output in following format:-

```
Id  iMId Time1 Time2 Time3  Time4
----------------------------------
1   4   1     3       5       7
       2500 5000   10000     20000
2   8   1     3      5         7
       2500 5000    10000    20000
```

I've tried:

```
SELECT sProfileId,iMerchantId,'Day1','Day2','Day3','Day4',dAmount 
FROM (SELECT RM.sProfileId,RM.iMerchantId,RC.iDays,RC.dAmount 
      FROM  tblRuleByMerchant RM 
      JOIN tblAlertRuleCummulativeData RC ON (RM.sProfileId=RC.sProfileId) ) AS d
PIVOT (max(RM.sProfileId) FOR RM.iMerchantId IN ('Day1','Day2','Day3','Day4')) piv
```

Comment: I assume you mean you want to format the output.. not the query. Query formatting will not change the way it runs.

Comment: Also, in order for your question to be answered, you HAVE TO show us your effort in writing the query (finding the solution), otherwise your question will have a high chance to get downvoted and closed.

Comment: Please show what you had done. At least 2 or 3 line would help us on starting point

Comment: I want a query. I tried select sProfileId,iMerchantId,'Day1','Day2','Day3','Day4',dAmount
from
(
 SELECT RM.sProfileId,RM.iMerchantId,RC.iDays,RC.dAmount 
 FROM tblRuleByMerchant RM
 JOIN tblAlertRuleCummulativeData RC ON (RM.sProfileId=RC.sProfileId)
) as d
pivot
(
  max(RM.sProfileId)
  for RM.iMerchantId in ('Day1','Day2','Day3','Day4')
) piv;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed `Time` column Value are fixed and that are `1,3,5,7`.

Below Query is similar to what you wanted to achieve.

```
select distinct T.id,T.iMid,
  (select amount from myTable
  where time = 1 and id = T.id and iMid = T.iMid) as Time1,
  (select amount from myTable
  where time = 3 and id = T.id and iMid = T.iMid) as Time2,
  (select amount from myTable
  where time = 5 and id = T.id and iMid = T.iMid) as Time3,
  (select amount from myTable
  where time = 7 and id = T.id and iMid = T.iMid) as Time4,
  2 as level
  from myTable T
 union All
select distinct T.id,T.iMid,1,3,5,7,1
  from myTable T
 order by id,level
```

**[Here is the SQLFiddel DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/74849/1)** with Similar pattern as you mentioned in Your Question.